# How to create .py to .exe of a pandas code?

Tags: pandas, pyinstaller

I have written some code that takes 2 excel files and merges them into a new one, called "output.xlsx".

The code is for another person that does not code, so I tried to convert it to .exe with pyinstaller:`pyinstaller --onefile 130919.py`, tried it without `--onefile` too.

The problem is that when I click the .exe file nothing happens, it does not create a new "output.xlsx" file for me.

the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',usecols=[0,1])
df2=df1['מספר שרטוט'].str.split(expand=True)
df3=df1['Run Time'].str.split(pat='*',expand=True)
min=df3[0].str.split(expand=True)
parallel=df3[1].str.split(expand=True)

run_time=df1['Run Time']

min=min[0]
parallel=parallel[0]
df2.drop([0, 3], axis = 1, inplace = True)


final=df2[1].str.split(")",expand=True)
char=df2[2].str.split(")",expand=True)
final.insert(1,"Parallel",parallel)
final.insert(1,"Minutes",min)
final.insert(1,"char",char[0])

final.drop(1, axis = 1, inplace = True)
print(final.head())

xl2=pd.read_excel('kitaron.xlsx')
print(xl2.head())
final.columns=['Det', 'char', 'Minutes', 'Parallel']
print(final.columns)

xl3=pd.merge(final,xl2,on='Det')
xl3.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: It appears that this is definitely a `pandas` issue. can you try  this code once --> `pyinstaller -F 130919.py`

Comment: still doesnt work :\ it creates an .exe file but doest produce the desired .xlsx file i've commanded it to do in the python code.

Comment: can you try to run the `.exe` file in command prompt? it there is any error thrown it would show there. If run directly as `.exe`, it will just close.

Comment: tried what you said, and this is my error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "130919.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
[17768] Failed to execute script 130919